Pass List variables to Flask's render_template - problem at the last 'return' line
While preparing metadata for images to transmit to template , I'm facing the problem that my  variable CollectionIPTCa:

CollectionIPTCa is initiated as [] (an empty list) in the first line of my ImagesCabWillA() function.
Later, it is successfully populated with items and subitems
(a 2 levels list: a collection of image files ,
with, for each of them, a small collection of metadata items)
CollectionIPTCa is still alive and populated at the before last line of the function
( this is tested OK in console mode on PythonAnyWhere platform);
but when packed in the last ***return *** instruction

return render_template("/Album2024a/Album2024b.htm", testarray =  testarray1, **collectionIPTC =  CollectionIPTCa**, CollectionIPTCmimic =  "CollectionIPTCmimic", myi =  i)

it is behaving as getting emptied: back to initiated state of []; Jinja2 receives only empty [].

NB : other parameters tested, more simple, are passed ok to Jinja : testarray , myi

I presume there is an error in my structured code
for p in ...
    if ...
        if ...
        else ....
    else ....

or then a bug somewhere

Here is extract of my flask_app.py code :
@app.route('/ImagesCabWillA/')
def  ImagesCabWillA():
    CollectionIPTCa=[]
    testarray1=[12,24]
    i=0
    for p in Path('static/ImagesCabWillA').glob("*.*"):
        if p.is_file() and p.suffix.lower() in (".jpg", ".jpeg"):
            CollectionIPTCa.append(["item " + str(i)])
            CollectionIPTCa[i].append(os.path.basename(p))
            info = iptcinfo3.IPTCInfo(p, force=True)
            if isinstance(info['object name'],bytes):
                CollectionIPTCa[i].append(info["object name"].decode("utf-8"))
                CollectionIPTCa[i].append(info["headline"].decode("utf-8"))
            else:
                print("info['object name'] is not byte type\n")
                continue
            i+=1
        else:
            print(os.path.basename(p) , "  is not a jpg file\n")
            continue
    print("CollectionIPTCa :")
    print(CollectionIPTCa)
    # CollectionIPTCa=['truc', 'much', ['trac', 'mach']] # this test was working ok)
    return render_template("/Album2024a/Album2024b.htm", testarray =  testarray1, collectionIPTC =  CollectionIPTCa, CollectionIPTCmimic =  "CollectionIPTCmimic", myi =  i)    # "i" doesn't work, i is ok (integer)


From there, you can see the tests I made on more simple variables to pass through the return instruction.

In console mode (not Flask served 'route', thus...), the value of CollectionIPTCa is (as expected :-) ):
[['item 0', '09_DSCF8528.JPG', 'Les débuts', 'Le living , WiFi'], ['item 1', '07_IMG-20220325-WA0021.jpeg', 'Le nouveau poêle', '~~'], ['item 2', '05_IMG-20220325-WA0014.jpeg', 'Vers la rrue Copinette', 'Centre Willerzie'], ['item 3', '06_IMG-20220517-WA001
3.jpeg', "L'Hotel de la Poste", '"LE" Restaurant-Café de Gedinne-Centre'], ['item 4', '01.jpg', 'La terrasse', 'Avant travaux'], ['item 5', 'DSCF9387Lite.JPG', 'titre chalet vu du bas', 'titre principal ::chalet vu du bas'], ['item 6', '04_IMG_20220207_1828
56.jpg', 'Sunset', 'Entre Willerzie et Rienne'], ['item 7', '02_DSCF0225.JPG', 'Panneaux solaires', 'Les 4 premiers (total 8 en 2024)'], ['item 8', '08_IMG_20220509_193214.jpg', 'Camping', 'pas sans la RTBF'], ['item 9', 'DSCF9384Lite.JPG', '03_IMG-20220517
-WA0006.jpeg', 'La Croix-Scaille,', 'Depuis la tour du Millénaire (frontière française)'], ['item 9']]


On the side of my template, everything is ok about passing simple variables and list, BUT NOT when CollectionIPTCa variable/parameter is involved:
{% set meta1 = "une donnée info sur image" %}
{% block content %}
<div>
<img style="max-width: 40%;"  src= "{{url_for('static',filename='ImagesCabWillA/07_IMG-20220325-WA0021.jpeg')}}">
Légende: {{meta1}}
</div>
<div> 
  <h2>CollectionIPTC</h2>
    {{collectionIPTC}}
  <h2>testarray</h2>
    {{testarray}}
  <h2>myi</h2>
    {{myi}}
</div>
{% endblock content %}


If you keep the prints in you view, you should see the contents of CollectionIPTCa in your web app's logs (you can redirect the output to the error log, as the server log is usually busier, by adding file=sys.stderr kwarg to the print call).
